# Edit text in file(UTF16)

Tags: vb.net, file, replace, filesystems, utf-16

I want replace 1 word in text file (file format is not .txt)
file Unicode is (UTF16)
few text example:

I D = " f f 0 3 4 a 9 2 - d d 9 f - 4 3 7 4 - a 8 a d - f 5 5 4 0 0 2 a 4 1 9 b "   I S S U E _ D A T E = " 2 0 1 7 - 0 2 - 1 6 T 1 7 : 2 9 : 1 8 . 9 7 0 2 2 9 4 Z "   S E Q U E N C E = " 0 "   M A N A G I N G _ A P P L I C A T I O N _ T O K E N = " " > < L I C E N S E   P U B L I C _ I D = " 3 A A - U J F - 8 K P "   U S E R N A M E = " N d a G 6 Z T w u v I X Z B i t h 8 g o d d Q x E r x 0 + O g M c t 0 2 3 f X K O E w = "   P A S S W O R D = " F 9 b n 6 b v w l f I 5 Z A 2 t h M h 9 d d s x Q L w = "   T Y P E = " **T R I A L** "   F L A G S = " 4 "   D I S P L A Y _ N A M E =

I want change T R I A L to other word

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard to modify your text file. Use the `IO` class to assign it to a text file, then use `String.Replace(oldValue As String, newValue As String)` to change your string. Then use `IO` again to save the string to the file. This should work so long as your file isn't open and being used in another program - regardless of file extensions.

An example, to help you, could be something such as this:

```
Dim myFileContents as String = IO.File.ReadAllText("Path\To\My\File\File.extension")
myFileContents = myFileContents.Replace("T R I A L", "Some other word")
IO.File.WriteAllText("Path\To\My\File\File.extension", myFileContents)
```

Modify the contents to suit your situation - however, this is only a basic implementation. Additionally, it is important to note that `String.Replace()` will change *all* occurrences of your word to the new word.

Comment: Me thinks his issue is more to do with the file encoding. Either he doesn't know how to read and write the correct format, or the text file has no header to identify it as Unicode and he needs to force it. I can't tell which from the question though.

Comment: with this code remove all space and changed UTF to UTF8 - not change T R I A l